# Parse notification on android app when there is upload to parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform, notifications, push-notification, android-notifications

I was wondering if there is any way for parse.com to send a push notification to my Android app when there is new upload. I want a notification to appear on my phone when 5 images has been uploaded from my raspberry pi to parse.com . I tried exploring the push notification function of parse.com but could not find such a function. I would also like to know if if there are any other methods to help alert users using my app when 5 pictures has been uploaded to parse.com. Any help would be appreciated, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [cloud code save hook](https://parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#cloud-code-aftersave-triggers) which will run each time an image is saved and it can trigger a [push notification](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Push.html).